# Rails: undefined method from a loop with no record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm looping through a table to get some values, and then I'm trying to loop another table to get more items:

My **Business** table looks like this

```
id        name          
1         Business 1    
2         Business 2
```

**Business Photo** table:

```
id        default_pic       business_id
1         blahblah.jpg      1
```

So if I'm trying to loop:

```
<% @b.each do |b| %>
   <%= b.name %>
   <%= b.business_photos.default_pic %>
<% end %>
```

I get `undefined method defaul_pic?` I believe because there's no more record after the second loop when its getting `Business 2`. Whats the rails way to check record association so I don't get this error?

This is how my models look:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :business_photos
end

class BusinessPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
end
```

Comment: what is @b? can you provide complete view file? and please provide the complete error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= b.business_photos.default_pic if defined?(b.business_photos.default_pic) %>
```

This is a conditional if statement we use each time we want to include a variable & are unsure of whether it's set. I've been looking for something which can prevent the error from showing through a .each (would take out so much logic from views), but I am yet to find one

Comment: This worked. Maybe someone else will have the answer about the .each